# Finding probability using Volume fraction

Tags: probability

*A bus line runs every $30$ minutes. If a passenger arrives at a stop randomly, what is the probability that he will have to wait more than $10$ minutes for the next bus?*

I solved this using probability distribution and I got the answer $\frac {2}{3}$ which is correct.

But I am told to solve this using volume fraction over some domain. In my attempt for doing this, I get a different answer $\frac {1}{12}$

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: The hand drawing is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the other person meant by "volume fraction over some domain", unless they meant a $1$-dimensional volume, i.e. an interval.

The only random variable is $W = $ waiting time, which is $U(0, 30)$.  This is the interval $(0, 30)$, of length $30$.

The event $W > 10$ is presented by the sub-interval $(10, 30)$, of length $20$.

Therefore, answer $= 20 / 30 = 2/3$.

---

It seems (I'm guessing here) you wish to introduce more variables.  E.g. Let $B = $ bus arrival time (modulo $30$ minutes, e.g. counted as time since the last exact hour or exact half-hour on the clock) and $P = $ passenger arrival time (similarly modulo $30$ minutes).  Then the state space ("volume") is $30 \times 30$ (not $30 \times 20$ as you drew).  Now waiting time $W = B - P$ (modulo $30$).  Draw the two parallel lines $W=0$ (**you didn't draw this**) and $W=10$ (you drew this) and note that the latter line "wraps around".  The narrow band between the two lines represent $W < 10$ and the complement area $W > 10$.  You should find that the complement has area $600$ so the answer is still $600/900 = 2/3$.

Answer (score 0):

@antkam I understood your explanation clearly. Thanks a lot. I also tried to solve it in a way. Can you see if I'm wrong somewhere in this attempt.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what your $P$ is.  Usually in "graphical" or "volume fraction" methods like this, the state space include all possible outcomes, whether good or bad.  In my 2-D version, $0 \le P \le 30$ because the person can arrive at any time (after the hour or half-hour on the clock).  In your formulation, what is $P$?  If your $P$ is defined as "person arrival time since last bus" then $P$ still has range $(0,30)$, and the "good" range is $(0,20)$ and this is a 1-D problem, the answer simply being $20/30 = 2/3$.  If this is the meaning of your $P$, there is no need to consider $B$.